# "Fermi golden rule" approximation in the form $\int_0^\tau dt_1 \int_0^{t_1} dt_2 e^{i\lambda(t_1-t_2)} \approx \tau \frac{i}{\lambda+i0}$

Tags: calculus, approximations, fermis-golden-rule

In Eq. (40) of the paper [PRB 74, 125319 (2006)](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.74.125319) ([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0604458)), the "golden rule approximation" is stated in the form of
$$\int_0^\tau dt_1 \int_0^{t_1} dt_2 \: e^{i\lambda(t_1-t_2)} \approx \tau \frac{i}{\lambda+i0}, \tag{$*$}$$
where one only keeps the leading order in $\tau$. (I think $\tau$ is large in the context of the paper.)

**Question**: *How can I understand this approximation, and how one may connect it to the "usual" golden rule about transition rate?*

By the way, exact evaluation of the integral gives
$$\int_0^\tau dt_1 \int_0^{t_1} dt_2 \: e^{i\lambda(t_1-t_2)} = \frac{e^{i\lambda \tau}-1-i\lambda\tau}{(i\lambda)^2}.$$
Maybe $(*)$ is to be understood in the distribution sense, i.e., for every smooth and rapidly decaying function $g(\lambda)$, we have
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\lambda \: \frac{e^{i\lambda \tau}-1-i\lambda\tau}{(i\lambda)^2} g(\lambda) \approx \tau \int_{-\infty}^\infty d\lambda \: \frac{i}{\lambda+i0} g(\lambda).$$
However, I cannot derive this result.

Comment: Could the approximation be that $\lambda \ggg 1/\tau$? in that case, your analyic result can be written as the paper result + terms that go like $1/\lambda^2$.

Comment: Yes, that's probably it. It says assuming the correlation time is much shorter than $\tau$ so assuming $1/\lambda \lll \tau$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact integral
$$\int_0^\tau dt_1 \int_0^{t_1} dt_2 \: e^{i\lambda(t_1-t_2)} = \frac{e^{i\lambda \tau}-1-i\lambda\tau}{(i\lambda)^2}$$
may be written
$$ = \frac{e^{i\lambda \tau}-1}{(i\lambda)^2}  -\frac{\tau}{i\lambda}$$
Now we are assuming that $\lambda \tau \gg 1$, so write it as
$$ = \frac{\tau^2 e^{i\lambda \tau}-1}{(i\tau \lambda)^2}  -\frac{\tau}{i\lambda} = \frac{i\tau}{\lambda} + \mathcal{O}(1/(\tau\lambda)^2)$$

Comment: Thanks for guessing appropriate conditions and deriving the result! I think the prescription $\lambda \to \lambda+i0$ is natural, since it makes the original integral decay exponentially.